# Is it possible to take screenshots on the 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

In Pokemon X and Y there are specific locations in the game that allows you to save what are essentially 3D screenshots from the upper screen using a virtual camera. This made me wonder - is it possible to take screenshots, 3D or otherwise, from within the 3DS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In many cases, **yes**.

There is **no "save screenshot to SD card" feature** in the 3DS as of right now. Some games allow you to take pictures **under certain conditions** (the camera man in Pokémon XY, the camera in Pilotwings Resort, pressing L + R in Animal Crossing New Leaf, etc.), but this **differs from game to game**.

With the **Miiverse**, however (which was added to 3DS in a firmware update), you **can** post whatever is on screen at the time **if that particular game has a Miiverse community** (and you are able to bring up the home menu, of course) - and then only in that particular community. After posting a screenshot on Miiverse, you can then access the image via Wii U, 3DS or the [Miiverse site](http://miiverse.nintendo.net/).

Comment: you can also get unofficial screen recorders

Comment: @qwertyk31 Yes, such as [this one](http://3dscapture.com/), but that saves video and images externally - not on your 3DS.

Comment: The inclusion of the Miiverse on the 3DS was mainly meant as a way to unify the 3DS store and the Wii U one, as people have started complaining about having to buy funds cards for both and having to buy GBA games on the Wii U, despite already owning them on the 3DS (through the 3DS Ambassador program). Still, it would be awesome if you could post screenshots from the 3DS onto the Miiverse as well.

Comment: @Nolonar "was mainly meant as a way" - It's not even out yet. Nintendo has only mentioned the NNID eShop merging so far, but it's not out of the question that it'll add more features related to NNID than that.

Comment: Miiverse *does* let you share screenshots on the 3DS. It's not exactly easy to do, since it requires you to go to the home menu and into Miiverse, but you *can* take screenshots now.

Comment: @Unionhawk Managed to forget about this answer, thanks for reminding me to update it!

Comment: Note that Miiverse will not allow you to post a screenshot if the game has the 3DS camera turned on.  (Presumably, this is to prevent people from posting inappropriate photographs.)

Comment: Miiverse is [being shut down](https://miiverse.nintendo.net/posts/AYMHAAADAAADV44YslslXw). =/

Comment: as of Nov 7th, 2017, it's no longer possible to do screenshots through Miiverse (RIP).

Answer (score 1):

If you have custom firmware installed on your 3DS, there are many homebrew tools able to take screenshots:

- If you have [Rosalina](https://github.com/AuroraWright/Luma3DS/wiki/Rosalina), press <kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>+<kbd>select</kbd> to open the menu, then select "Take screenshot (slow)". It's indeed slow (about 10 seconds), but otherwise woks fine, even with extended memory games like Pokemon X/Y.
- If you run the game via [TestMenu](https://www.3dbrew.org/wiki/3DS_Development_Unit_GUI#Test_Menu), suspend it using <kbd>Home</kbd>, then press <kbd>L</kbd> to take the screenshot. I'm not using this tool so cannot tell how well it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you pause in "super smash bros" during a single player (and maybe multiplayer), L and R will take pictures which you can see in the 3DS camera along with your other pictures.