# How can I record 3DS Footage?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Is there a way I can record 3DS Footage (with out the use of a camera)? I have seen plenty of Youtube people record themselves playing Pokemon games. I know some use a camera, but what about the other ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to take screenshots on the 3DS?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142363/is-it-possible-to-take-screenshots-on-the-3ds)

Comment: I assumed most Youtubers used an emulator to record from, not an actual 3DS.

Comment: @geobits But one can not emulate online game play, such as a SSB4 fight or an online Pokemon battle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I do not have personal experience with any of these devices or shops.

Essentially, you need to modify the 3DS to intercept the video data and send it through an external output. What you need is specifically a 3DS capture board like [this one](http://3dscapture.com/).

The site above only allows you to send in your system to have the modification performed, and it has to be the original 3DS, not the 3DSXL or 2DS. You can also buy pre-modded units from http://www.3dsvideocapture.com/.

To the best of my knowledge there are no DIY kits available anywhere; you have to send your device to the seller for installation, and this is, of course, only going to make it even more expensive. Unless you are expecting to make heavy use of this functionality, it is unlikely to be worth the cost.

If you happen to be a licensed 3DS developer, you can also obtain a development unit with capture functionality - however, these are not only significantly more expensive, but they are also [not able to run retail cartridges](http://3dbrew.org/wiki/3DS_Development_Unit_Software), so it is only useful if you want to record a game you have developed yourself.

Comment: Okay, from this question, I will have to propose a different question. Still bummed it costs so much.